# Pyspark dataframes adding columns from function returns

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a data frame and I want to add columns. I want to randomly allocate values to the rows of my new column from a function result. Like this.

```
def getRandomString():
  return "woteva" + str(randint(0,100))

df = df.withColumn("MyNewColumn", lit(getRandomString()))
```

In the result I am getting my first random result but repeats the first random output for all rows.

How can I get a new result per row ?

Answer (score 0):

[lit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lit.html) creates a column of literal (constant) value. This means when your code is executed the function `getRandomString()` is called *once* and the return value is used to create a column with a constant value.

To execute `getRandomString()` once per row, you can turn `getRandomString()` into an [udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html). Udfs will be called by Spark once per row.

By default udfs are considered to be deterministic. If this is not the case an udf must be marked [nondeterministic](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html?highlight=asnondeterministic)

```python
import random
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

randomstringudf = F.udf(lambda: "woteva" + str(random.randint(0,100)), 
    T.StringType()).asNondeterministic()
df.withColumn("MyNewColumn", randomstringudf()).show()
```